# Hadoop find hostname of task attempt

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to programatically determine which task attempts run on which tasktracker in my cluster when submitting map reduce jobs to hadoop.  I have found that I can get most of the task data from the JobClient like so:

`jobClient.getMapTaskReports(jobID)`

but not the hostname of the machine that a task attempt succeeded on.  Does anybody know how to get the hostname from the task attempt id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JobClient](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html) gives you a so called [NetworkedJob](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.NetworkedJob.html) when submitting. It has a method called `getTaskCompletionEvents`.

That returns you an array of `TaskCompletionEvent` that happened, those [contain the HTTP address of the tasktracker that ran a task](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/hadoop/hadoop-1.0.3/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/TaskCompletionEvent.html#getTaskTrackerHttp%28%29).

From that point you can parse the host from the URL.