# Get the hosts for an hadoop job

Tags: hadoop

I need to get the hosts (so the actual machines) where the differente tasks (mapper and reducer) of a Hadoop Job run. So I got a long running job and I need to retrieve the hosts where the tasks are currently running. I need this information in an external programm, so not inside the actual jobs.

I know that I can use `hadoop job -list-attempt-ids  job_201307251119_0004 map running`
 to get the task attempts, but this does not show me the hosts.

I also know that I can [use the `JobClient` to retrieve the host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712038/hadoop-find-hostname-of-task-attempt) of a *finished* task. But in my case, the task is still running.

The only solution which came to my mind was to parse the Job-Tracker-HTTP-Interface HTML page which contains the host in the URLs which point to the log-files. But this does not seem like the right way to go, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to get the hostname where a mapper/reducer is currently running, you could write a few additional java lines inside the mapper/reducer to itself to find it. Perhaps :

```
String hostname = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

IDK if this is exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm not inside the mapper, I'm an external process which only has the job id.